# How to edit/unpost a posted bill in GnuCash 2.6.1

Tags: gnucash, billing

I created a vendor bill and posted it.  After posting it I realized I made a mistake in the amount entered in the bill.  The GnuCash Help Manual states on page 79:

> Before you can edit a posted bill, you will need to Unpost it.

However, it provides no instructions on how to unpost a bill.

Note that I have tried deleting the transactions in the expenses account for the vendor, and in accounts payable but both return a warning that transaction is read-only and first I need to unpost the bill.

I am using Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 3):

This has an easy answer.  In version 2.6.1 the icons are so large the unpost icon is hidden at the rightmost edge of the tool bar.  Just click on the down arrow and you will see it.